# Identify the distance of face captured from the webcam

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, math

I have a picture of face captured by webcam, i would like to know the distance of the detected face from the webcam.

[image]

To achieve the same, I am trying out with finding the area of triangle formed by two eye centers and a nose tip and observe the variation in the area when i move away from the camera by a known distance.  However, I am unsuccessful in my trails.

Need help in calculating the distance of the face from the webcam. Please note that whatever method I am gonna use should be person independent as I cannot control the people whose gonna walkin in front of the camera

Comment: You realize that the number of centimeters per pixel depends on how far away the object is from the camera, right?

Comment: @Eric In this case, distance of the object from camera is unknown. In fact that is what I need to find as the end result

Comment: Maybe start by sharing all the information you do know... do you have the picture? Is there anything of a known size in the picture that you could use for calibration? Is the focal length of the lens fixed/known?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have edited the question with full info. To answer your question, I  cannot calculate the size of the face as I am not sure whose gonna detect at what distance. Camera's focal length is fixed though

Comment: "should be person independent" - this is not possible - you're going to have to assume that everyone's face is the same size

Comment: @Eric Well, here is what I have figured out! Please let me know if this makes sense. Please refer to my answer below!!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried constructing a characteristic triangle of a human face as given below:

[image]

Then I have the used the following equation: [image]

Where "d" is the distance, ax and ay are camera parameters. [image] and [image] are areas of characteristic angle in Captured face and real face respectively.

Let us assume that, face is detected at the distance (d1) and calculated [image]. Now, i have moved away from camera by 5 CMs and consider that distance as (d2) and noted the area of triangle formed on captured face.

Using the above two equations, ax, ay and [image] are constant and solve as follows:

[image]. Here I also assumed that in real world, the area of characteristic triangle is going to constant and doesn't vary from person to person.

Now that we have value of K, we can calculate the distance of detected face by using the following equation:

[image]

Please let me know if this approach makes sense